# Email difference algorithm

Tags: email, email-threading

I would like to replicate gmails functionality to "magically" not show irrelevant quoted stuff in emails but still showing mostly relevant stuff. Are there any libraries which can help me find the text that is actually new and should be shown? Or do you have any suggestions on how to proceed?

I do know which two messages belong together and which one is the answer to the other but I would love to only show relevant text.

Comment: php would be optimal if not then c, ruby what ever I'd rewrite it to fit my needs :)